# Node specific locking in concurrency friendly linked lists in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list, locks

[THIS](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/choose-concurrency-friendly-data-structu/208801371?pgno=2) is an article about why linked list are great for multi threaded environment. Author says that linked list are so concurrency friendly as user can acquire locks selectively on the operated nodes and its effected neighbours .. leaving other nodes open for other threads.

I am new to multi threading. Can someone please suggest how can we acquire a lock just on a node and its next and previous node ?

Answer (score 0):

The [ConcurrentLinkedDequeue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) and [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) in the jre provide behavior similar to what is described.